# Hive - Case statement in join - error

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am facing a problem when using the case statement in a left join in Hive.

Hive query below  -

```
select 
    m.InventoryId,
    m.dataproviderid,   
    m.dealerid,   
    case when ti.makeid is null then T.MakeId else ti.makeid end,
    ti.makename,
    ti.modelname,
    ti.yearindependentmodelid,
from InventoryMRout111 m
join InventoryTrim111 T on (m.InventoryId = T.InventoryId)
left join Styleinfo TI on ti.configuratorsourceid = 2122 
and 
(case 
                          when t.chid is not null and  
t.chid = ti.chid then 1
                          when t.mdlid is not null and t.mdlid = 
ti.mdlid then 1
                          when t.makeid is not null and t.makeid = ti.makeid 
then 1
                          else 0
                          end )                        
left join NewMinYear111 MY on (1=1)
where T.Trimsource in ('ranker','Match')
and m.Status = 'SUCCESS'
```

Error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10017]: Line 20:26 Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '0'
```

Any ideas what has to be fixed here ?

I also tried moving the case statement to the where clause..

```
select 
    m.InventoryId,
    m.dataproviderid,   
    m.dealerid,   
    case when ti.makeid is null then T.MakeId else ti.makeid end,
    ti.makename,
    ti.modelname,
    ti.yearindependentmodelid,
from InventoryMRout111 m
join InventoryTrim111 T on (m.InventoryId = T.InventoryId)
left join Styleinfo TI on ti.configuratorsourceid = 2122                       
left join NewMinYear111 MY on (1=1)
where T.Trimsource in ('ranker','Match')
and m.Status = 'SUCCESS'
and
(case 
                          when t.chid is not null and  
t.chid = ti.chid then 1
                          when t.mdlid is not null and t.mdlid = 
ti.mdlid then 1
                          when t.makeid is not null and t.makeid = ti.makeid 
then 1
                          else 0
                          end )  ;
```

But I get this error -

```
FAILED: ClassCastException org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.WritableIntObjectInspector cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.primitive.BooleanObjectInspector
```

Any advice on what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like second error says you must return booleans explicitly instead of 0 and 1 in case statement.

The implicit conversion table [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Overview) says boolean-to-int is not handled automatically.

For BOOLEAN values, the literals are TRUE and FALSE, with no quotation marks and case-insensitive.